# SurveyMonkey Webhook - Response expected

Tags: surveymonkey

From the docs at https://developer.surveymonkey.net/api/v3/#webhooks and trying out the feature I understand that webhooks first do a HEAD and then POST call to my webhook receiver public API.

Does the webhook POST callback to my receiver API require a response from it??

Many webhooks pay attention to responses and re-send requests if the application errors out. Just wanted to understand how SurveyMonkey deals with responses.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this should be specified in the documentation, but no, SurveyMonkey doesn't expect a response, as in it doesn't expect any particular body returned to us.

That said it does expect you to return a 2xx HTTP status code (which is usually automatically handled by any web server framework you use).